# Saving on-screen animation as a video in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I need to save an on-screen animation (finger drawing) as a video (preferably) or animated gif. The finger drawing part is done.  Are there any video editing javascript libraries (preferably React) which I can use to acheive this? If not, is there any other way to do this? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: You can check out https://github.com/spite/ccapture.js/ and see it it suits your needs

Comment: @AntoineGuillien thats probably something I am looking for, I am not sure it it would work with React Native though..